# Custom Transition Between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

Can somebody explain why my fromViewController is nil? I am trying to understand custom transition animations in iOS going back and forth between two different view controllers.

Removing the guard part of my code and modifying it a little bit, my present animation works, but I cannot figure out how to implement the dismiss animation. Any suggestions?

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)
{
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    guard
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from),
        let toViewController = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)
    else
    {
        print("Nope")
        return
    }

    containerView.addSubview(toViewController)

    if (presentationMode == .Present)
    {
        toViewController.alpha = 0.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
            animations: {
                toViewController.alpha = 1.0
            },
            completion: {
                _ in transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }
```

Edit: This is where I use the animation

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let secondVC = segue.destination as! SignUpViewController
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self

}
extension LoginViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
{   
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
    {
        print("Presenting")

        presentationTransition.presentationMode = .Present

        return presentationTransition
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
    {
        print("Dismissing")

        presentationTransition.presentationMode = .Dismiss

        return presentationTransition
    }


}`
```

Comment: Well since you're adding the view, all you need to do is remove it. Create the animation you want, then use `toViewController.removeFromSuperview()` to remove it.

Comment: Your `fromViewController` syntax look ok. Can you post the code that uses this animation?

Comment: @FangmingNing Yeah, sure! I apologize for the late response. I went off to get myself something to eat :D

Comment: @Jimmy I did try that, but the problem is that since fromViewController is nil, it won't pass through the guard statement and simply returns exiting the function.

Comment: First, just to clarify, what you're calling `fromViewController` is not the view controller. It's the view. (Same is true with `toViewController`.) And if you have the "from" view, it's `let from = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from).view`. I've found it more reliable to retrieve the view controller and then the view from that.

Comment: @Rob It still doesn't seem to work. The fromViewController keeps being nil and therefore just returns exiting the fucntion..

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue (see [my rendition](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/dc8a8dc66f4f002699f793c9945c1a59)). The only thing I'd note is that the header file for `view(forKey:)` says that it "may return `nil` which would indicate that the animator should not manipulate the associated view controller's view." Perhaps there's something about how your presented view controller or its view has been created that makes it non-manipulatable. To help you, we need to first be able to reproduce your issue and I suspect the problem rests somewhere other than the above code. We need more info.

Comment: @Rob Hi! Thank you for commenting on the post. I still haven't figured out why the guard statement returns nil. I'd love to provide you with anything to help me solve the problem. Do you have anything specific you'd like me to provide?

Comment: I’d suggest creating a blank, simple little project that reproduces the problem and upload that somewhere for us. Just two view controllers. Just enough to reproduce the problem. It’s hard to help you solve it if we can’t reproduce it. (And as a benefit, sometimes, in the process of trying to reproduce it, you’ll figure out what’s causing it, all by yourself.)

Comment: @Rob Hi again, Rob! I tried creating a whole new project implementing the code you provided and everything seems to be perfectly working! Something must be completely wrong with my LoginViewController, which is where I use the animation. I have no idea what, though. I tried removing all button references and whatever I could think of might cause issues, the guard statement still goes nil.

Comment: Alright. The problem seems to be in the view controller that I am currently trying to present. I added a new view controller and used a button to show that new view controller, which actually worked. I wonder what the issue might be. I guess I'll just recreate the view controller and see what happens.

Comment: Found the issue. If you click on the yellow circle on top of any view controller (which shows the name of the view controller), go to the Attribute Inspector and change "presentation" to "over current context". This causes the nil issue for me. Damn... what a stupid mistake. I have never spent as much time trying to fix an error as I have with this one xD